# Unable to use = operator in a "If" statement

Tags: vb.net

Why can't I use = operator over here. Anyway to solve this problem ?

```
 If PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.pic001 Then
       x = 1
    Else
       x = 0
    End If
```

The error message is:

> Operator '=' is not defined for types
>   'System.Drawing.Image' and
>   'System.Drawing.Bitmap'

Comment: As the error message says, the operator '=' is not defined for the types you are comparing. i.e. it is not possible to compare a System.Drawing.**Image** to a System.Drawing.**Bitmap**
Why are you comparing two images?

Comment: if the image in the picturebox is the compared image then I want x = 1 else x = 0.

Comment: then you need to compare like for like. As Michel says in his answer the types you are comparing are not the same.

Comment: @Tony So there is no way to check whether the same specified image is used or not ?

Comment: I'll convert my comments to an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that PictureBox1.Image references the same Image object as My.Resources.pic001, then you could use:

```
If Object.ReferenceEquals(PictureBox1.Image, My.Resources.pic001) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the operator '=' is not defined for the types you are comparing. i.e. it is not possible to compare a System.Drawing.**Image** to a System.Drawing.**Bitmap**

You will need to compare the images bit-by-bit or create a hash value for each one and compare those.

There is a thread here which has a C# example (it shouldn't be hard to convert to VB):

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=363130

**EDIT:** There might be another solution, **I have not tried it and I don't know if, and it probably won't, work as expeted** but there is an `Equals()` method available on `System.Drawing.Image` (and `Bitmap` is derived from `Image`). You might have some luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `Image`s to `Bitmap`s, they are different things.

Comment: i just want to check whether the image used in the picture-box is the given image or not

Comment: `Bitmap` inherits from `Image`, so an `Image` reference may or may not reference a `Bitmap` object.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
    Dim pbImage1 As Image = My.Resources.Swamp 'imported from a file called Swamp.jpg
    Dim pbimage2 As Image = My.Resources.Dusty 'Imported from a file called Dusty.jpg

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = pbImage1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If PictureBox1.Image Is pbImage1 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = pbimage2
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = pbImage1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```